# adding a sleep / timer in a kernel module

Tags: kernel-module

I need to do task at regular intervals in a kernel module after the module has loaded. How do I achieve that. The examples on the web show a hello world in the init_module and exit_module. I have not seen any literature on how to code regularly occuring events inside a kernel module. Can someone please provide inputs?
Thanks

Comment: By 'kernel-module' do you mean Linux kernel?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article for Linux: [Kernel APIs, Part 3: Timers and lists in the 2.6 kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-timers-list/?ca=drs-)

It has an example module that uses both the simple timer API, and highres timers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at chapter 7 of LDD:

http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this timer tutorial for linux kernel](http://www.embeddedcircle.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=3)